# number of files in a folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum number of files (or folders) that can be stored in a single folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/18692/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-or-folders-that-can-be-stored-in-a-single-f)

Where can I find specification on how many files are allowed in a folder in a windows server 2003 setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/18692/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-or-folders-that-can-be-stored-in-a-single-f/18697#18697).

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of files per NTFS volume is 4,294,967,295 . So in theory the maximum number of files on an NTFS volume that only has one folder would be 4,294,967,294.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum number of files in a single folder on an ntfs filesystem is 4,294,967,295 files.

Answer (score 1):

If using NTFS, here are more details about limitations : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfs#Limitations