# How to increase the Nested Folder Limit Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

The server is having error Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2 ID 513. While googling I found that one of he possible causes was Microsoft.net having more than 1,000 sub-folders and in fact it has 1,069 folders. Is there a way to increase the limit to lets say 1100 folders.

Comment: How did you determine this is related to nested folders (which is the *depth* of the tree - not the number of entries in a single level)? Everything I see related to this error is related to "*Cryptographic Services failed while processing the OnIdentity()*"

Comment: I came across this link 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734021(v=ws.10).aspx
where user VasekB mentions "This issue occurs because Windows Server limits any directory from containing more than 1,000 subdirectories." so I went and checked how many folders Microsoft.Net had (1060) and assumed that was the issue.

Comment: 1000 subdirectories in a given level of the tree shouldn't matter at all: http://serverfault.com/q/18692/2321